# How to help our 7 year old "get to the point" of his stories. Or is this a developmental stage?

Tags: communication, language-development

Our 7 year old takes a long time to tell a story or relate an event. He will repeat sentences over again if he stumbles over a word or detail. He will  ramble on over a minor detail. How can we help him "tighten up" his story telling? Or is this a developmental stage that will pass??

Answer (score 10):

In my experience, it's something they learn how to do with practice, and with listening to others do the same thing.  It's not really feasible for anyone here to say if your child is at, below, or above the norm for their age; if you want to know that, your best resource is your child's teacher.

Something I do to help my youngest work on this is to ask him to recount events of his day.  I largely let him go at his own pace.  When he begins to get distracted, I gently redirect with probing questions where I concisely reiterate what he'd said to that point- something like, "You were telling me about your science experiment with magnets.  I think you mentioned stacking them up.  What happened when you did that?"  That helps him get back on track, but it also shows him how he could have told me the information in a more concise way - but without being condescending or lecturing him.

I try to make it not unidirectional, though;  I also try to tell him about what I'm doing, or how my day went.  That gives me a chance to model the conversation, and he can learn how to do his side of the conversation by listening to mine.

Comment: I like that you are also showing your son, by example, how to listen.

Answer (score 0):

Your kid will sort this out as they develop, just give them the opportunity.

Just look at how some comedians behave: some tell long rambling stories and others are more comfortable with short quick one-liners.

The opportunity to express themselves is the most important - you give them that by engaging with them fully. If there's nothing to distract you, being able to really listen is invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

He's learning how to process his memories. Ask a question when he starts to fumble to help him get back on track.

(ex: "oh my, I bet that was funny! What else happened?")